# How to measure the difference between two random forest models?

Tags: multiple-regression, random-forest, distance-functions

Suppose that I have training data defined as a set of N records (or samples) defined by its attributes (or descriptors, features, as you prefer), and I trained two random forest models with two parts of the data. I was thinking... How to measure the difference (or distance) between such models (or internal parameters/weights)?

Comment: What exactly you want to compare? You can compare preference, predictions, etc.

Comment: I would like to compare the internal parameters of two random forest models trained with the same set of attributes (i.e. the model, not the predictions, which may be an obvious task). For example, one would compare linear models with their slopes.